# select itemName() from amazon simpledb using boto

Tags: amazon-simpledb, boto

I'm trying to get itemName() from a simpleDB select query using boto, but doing `select itemName() from domain where attribute = 'foo' limit 10` gives me an result set with 10 items but they are all empty.

I've also tried `` select `itemName()` from domain where attribute = 'foo' `` and `select itemName from domain where attribute = 'foo'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Item objects returned are empty because you are not asking for any attributes in the query.  The itemName is not really an attribute.  It is stored as a special value on the Item object that is accessible as item.name.

Comment: 9 months later I find this and thank you - couldn't find that in the boto docs.